# React/Javascript: How to check within two ranges of number in an array should not overlap when submit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a list of values which is having start and end address values. when i submit these following values i should compare these all start and end address and it should not repeat the existing range within values / overlap.

```
[
{
    "id": 23,
    "startAddress": 10,
    "endAddress": 15,
    
},
{
    "id": 24,
    "startAddress": 11,
    "endAddress": 13,
    
},
{
    "id": 25,
    "startAddress": 21,
    "endAddress": 23,
    
}
```

I have tried the following things

```
const findDuplicateRanges = data => {
    const addressRanges = new Map() 
            for (const item of data) {
        const addressRange = `${item.startAddress}-${item.endAddress}`

        if (addressRanges.has(addressRange)) {
            addressRanges.set(addressRange, addressRanges.get(addressRange) + 1)
        } else {
            addressRanges.set(addressRange, 1)
        }
    }

    const duplicateRanges = []

    for (const [ range, count ] of addressRanges) {
        if (count > 1) {
            duplicateRanges.push(range)
        }
    }

    return duplicateRanges
}
```

But it is not working correctly. For example, when i give 1 to 5, again if i start with 2 it is accepting. I am blank here to implement

Comment: If you have a value like this `{start: 11,end:17}` . what do you to do?? how do you want to campare?

Comment: 11 is already taken in the first item, so that should not repeat again.

Comment: only the start is important?

Comment: No, whatever number exists in the ranges it should not repeat again. For example, start:5 and End:8, so we cannot use the values 5,6,7,8 again for the ranges. We can use 9to 11 or 1 to 4 like wise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's way simpler to check every item against all others:

```js
const findDuplicateRanges = data => {
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    const a = data[i];

    for (let j = i + 1; j < data.length; ++j) {
      const b = data[j];
      if (a.startAddress <= b.endAddress && a.endAddress >= b.startAddress) {
        console.log(`overlapping range: ${Math.max(a.startAddress, b.startAddress)}-${Math.min(a.endAddress, b.endAddress)}`);
        console.log(a, b);
      }
    }
  }
}

findDuplicateRanges([
  {
    "id": 23,
    "startAddress": 10,
    "endAddress": 15,
  },
  {
    "id": 24,
    "startAddress": 11,
    "endAddress": 13,
  },
  {
    "id": 25,
    "startAddress": 21,
    "endAddress": 23,
  },
  {
    "id": 26,
    "startAddress": 18,
    "endAddress": 22,
  }
])
```

You can improve on that if you first sort the list by startAddress and endAddress. Now overlapping elements are next to each other/close by. As soon as you find a pair that does not overlap, you can stop the inner loop.

```js
const findDuplicateRanges = data => {
  data.sort((a, b) => a.startAddress - b.startAddress || a.endAddress - b.endAddress);

  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    const a = data[i];
    for (let j = i + 1; j < data.length; ++j) {
      const b = data[j];

      if(b.startAddress > a.endAddress) break;
      
      console.log(`overlapping range: ${b.startAddress}-${Math.min(a.endAddress, b.endAddress)}`);
      console.log(a, b);
    }
  }
}

findDuplicateRanges([
  {
    "id": 23,
    "startAddress": 10,
    "endAddress": 20,
  },
  {
    "id": 24,
    "startAddress": 11,
    "endAddress": 13,
  },
  {
    "id": 25,
    "startAddress": 21,
    "endAddress": 23,
  },
  {
    "id": 26,
    "startAddress": 18,
    "endAddress": 22,
  }
])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the immediate response